# Excel VBA: Copy data from MS Project to Excel and back

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, ms-project

I know you can export data with MSP to Excel.
Still the manager wants me to write a vba script.

There is a schedule in MSP and some data in Excel belonging together. Data from MSP is pasted into Excel, an xlookup checks, whether some values changed. Only then a permission is given to start certain activities from the schedule. This process has legal reasons.

The process:

1. User opens Excel and starts script via a button click
2. User choses the correct MSP file
3. Data in MSP in the columns A:B  is copied to the excel with the button into columns A:B (how to make vba look for the correct header name? The view in MSP is not fixed, how can i reference the position correctly? Can I force MSP to use a certain custom view?)
4. FYI: Xlookup (already working) checks, whether a condition is met, and grants a permission in German "Freigabe erteilt". The permission, in quotation marks, is written into the cells as string.
5. Copy the column C to the column C in MSP (Again: How to make VBA find the right header, since the columns can move/ are hidden in MSP and not with absolute positions as in excel)

Bonus 1: Any suggestions fo performance improvements?
Bonus 2: Help me to make the whole process better, use Power BI or sth else?

As of now everything works up until I have to copy the info from MSP to Excel and back.
I tried to use standard excel logic but it seems MSP has to be treated in another way. I'm confused when to use which syntax

I saw another thread with a similar problem but it focuses on performance, which is secondary to me. I'm also new to Vba and it is still very difficult for me to look at other solutions and how to implement them into my code, since there's always little stuff I need to change and I don't even know how to search for it becasue I don't knwo the name.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DatenAktualisieren()


    Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application ' Microsoft Project Application
    Dim ProjFile As Variant ' Path to the Microsoft Project file
    Dim ProjSheet As MSProject.Project ' Microsoft Project Worksheet
    Dim ExcelBook As Workbook
    
    
    
    
    Set ProjApp = CreateObject("Msproject.Application") **'Bonus1: CreateObject -> GetObject? I read somewhere it can speed up the script, since nothing is visible, which.. I don't know needs more processing power?**
    
    ' Paths to MS Project and Excel files
    ' standard drive is C, this function has to be pointed to the destination: drive X, where all project files are located
    ChDrive "X"
    ChDir "X:<filepath>"
    ProjFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Project Files (*.mpp), *.mpp", _
    Title:="MS Project Datei auswählen", _
    MultiSelect:=False)
    
    If ProjFile = "False" Then 'GetOpenFilename returns boolean, not an object/string/integer, as one might   think!
            Exit Sub
    End If



    ' Open the MS Project file
    If ProjFile <> False Then
    
        ProjApp.FileOpen Name:=ProjFile
        Set ProjSheet = ProjApp.ActiveProject
        ProjApp.Visible = True
        'until now everything works as expected

        'copy column a:b from MSP to Excel

        ' wtf am I doing here?

''''''''
'this is the critical part imho

        ProjApp.Range("A1:B5000").Copy
        
        ExcelBook = ThisWorkbook
        ExcelBook.Sheet(1).Range("A1:B5000").PasteSpecial
            
        'Copy new Data back from Excel to MSP
        ExcelBook.Range("C1:C5000").Copy
        ProjApp.Range("C1:C5000").PasteSpecial
'''''''''           
            
    End If
    


    ' Clean up
    
    Set ProjSheet = Nothing
    Set ProjApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> As of now everything works up until I have to copy the info from MSP
> to Excel and back. I tried to use standard excel logic but it seems
> MSP has to be treated in another way.

Yes, as MS Project has a different purpose than Excel, it has a different [object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/project) and Excel logic does not apply. One key thing to remember is that the views in Project are not at all the same as different sheets in Excel.

The foundation of Project are the tasks and they can be shown in different views, in different orders, filtered, etc. When copying data from Project to Excel try not to think of it as like copying a range from one Excel file to another. Instead, copy tasks one-by-one, or if performance is an issue, make an array of tasks and copy the array to Excel.

The code below copies task data from the project and puts it into columns A and B in the Excel file. Then the data from column C is copied back to the tasks.

```
Private Sub DatenAktualisieren()


    Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application ' Microsoft Project Application
    Dim ProjFile As Variant ' Path to the Microsoft Project file
    Dim ProjSheet As MSProject.Project ' Microsoft Project Worksheet
    Dim ExcelBook As Workbook
    
        
    ' Paths to MS Project and Excel files
    ' standard drive is C, this function has to be pointed to the destination: drive X, where all project files are located
    ChDrive "X"
    ChDir "X:<filepath>"
    ProjFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Project Files (*.mpp), *.mpp", _
        Title:="MS Project Datei auswählen", _
        MultiSelect:=False)
    
    If ProjFile = "False" Then 'GetOpenFilename returns boolean, not an object/string/integer, as one might   think!
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Open the MS Project file
    If ProjFile <> False Then
    
         ' if Project is already open, get a reference to it, otherwise open it
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ProjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
        If ProjApp Is Nothing Then
            Set ProjApp = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
        End If
        ProjApp.Visible = True
   
        ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        ProjApp.FileOpen Name:=ProjFile
        Set ProjSheet = ProjApp.ActiveProject
        
        Set ExcelBook = ThisWorkbook
        Dim ExcelSheet As Worksheet
        Set ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.Sheets(1)
        ExcelSheet.Range("A1:B5000").Clear
        
        ' copy data from Project to Excel
        Dim fldProcessCode As Long
        fldProcessCode= ProjApp.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Process Code")
        Dim r As Long
        r = 1
        Dim tsk As Task
        For Each tsk In ProjSheet.Tasks
            r = r + 1
            ExcelSheet.Cells(r, 1) = tsk.UniqueID               ' pick the field you want to put in Column A
            ExcelSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tsk.GetField(fldProcessCode)  ' pull value from custom field 
        Next tsk
            
        'Copy new Data back from Excel to MSP
        ExcelSheet.Calculate
        r = 1
        For Each tsk In ProjSheet.Tasks
            r = r + 1
            tsk.Text1 = ExcelSheet.Cells(r, 3)      ' pick the Task field where Column C data should go
        Next tsk
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Tip 1: When automating another application (in this case MS Project), always set the Visible property to True immediately so that the user can respond to unexpected pop-up messages.

Tip 2: Consider using a different variable name for the project file as "sheet" has no meaning in MS Project. Typically "proj" or "project" is used either alone or as a prefix or suffix.

Tip 3: To get the value from a custom task field--either an enterprise field, or a local field with a customized name where the underlying field name is not known--use the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) method of the application object to first get the FieldID and then use the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method of the Task object to get the value.

Comment: That's more than I could hope for, thanks!

The two columns I want to chose from in MSP are from a custom view with custom names, how can I reference these? You picked some of the standard ones "UniqueID" and "Start", if I see that correctly.

Comment: If it's a custom name for a built-in field such as Text1 is labeled "Team Lead", then use `tsk.Text1`. If it is an enterprise custom field or the underlying field is unknown, use the [FieldNameToFieldConstant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant) method of the application object to first get the FieldID and then use the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method of the Task object to get the value.

Comment: Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.fieldnametofieldconstant they talk about project server, I only have the professional 3 version

I'm still confused how to get the enterprise custom names aka custom columns. They're only visible with a special view selected in MSP. How to do this in the code?

Comment: Try not to think of it as a "column" seen only in a "view". The data is in a field which is a property of the task object (just like UniqueID, Start, Finish, etc) and could be seen in many views, but more importantly can be retrieved by using the GetField method of the task object. See the updated code for how to use FieldNameToFieldConstant and GetField to pull data from an enterprise field.